# it works in a loop, but not when the for loop is in a funciton, why?

Tags: r

I want to make a function to change name of a vector when it matches another vector. It works when I write it as a for loop, like so:

```
df <- 1:5
df2 <- data.frame(id=3:7, name=LETTERS[1:5]) 

for(i in 1:length(df)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if(df[i]==df2$id[j]){
      df[i] <- df2$name[j]
    }
  }
}
df
#> [1] "1" "2" "A" "B" "C"
```

But not when I put it in a function, like so:

```
match <- function(df,df2){
  for(i in 1:length(df)) {
    for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){
      if(df[i]==df2$id[j]){
        df[i] <- df2$name[j]
      }
    }
  }
}
df <- match(df,df2)
df
#> NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function has no return value.  (ie It returns `NULL`.) So `df` is `NULL` after you assign the function's return value to it.

Comment: We need to return the object from the function, add return(df) on the last line of the funcition.

Comment: `match` is the name of a useful built-in function, so it might not be the best choice of a name for your own function.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the df inside the function.

```r
match <- function(df,df2){
  for(i in 1:length(df)) {
    for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){
      if(df[i]==df2$id[j]){
        df[i] <- df2$name[j]
      }
    }
  }
  df
}
df <- 1:5
df2 <-data.frame(id=3:7, name=LETTERS[1:5]) 
df <- match(df, df2)
df
#> [1] "1" "2" "A" "B" "C"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As **R** is a vectorized language, loops are not necessary here. What about using the buil-in `match`:

```r
tmp <- df2$name[match(df, df2$id)]
df <- ifelse(is.na(tmp), df, tmp)
df
# [1] "1" "2" "A" "B" "C"
```

This can of course be wrapped by a function.

As an alternative, one can also use a "join" function, e.g. `left_join` from package **dplyr**.